# getting the least time difference in a column based on parameter

Tags: python, pandas

This is my reproducible data-

```
raw_data = {'file': [123, 342, 223, 134, 235,233], 
            'identity': [12, 12, 12, 12,14,14], 
            'line': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6], 
            'date': ['10/27/2013','10/27/2013', '10/27/2013', '10/27/2013', '10/20/2013','10/20/2013'],
            'time': ['13:20:00', '13:20:30', '13:21:00', '13:21:30', '15:40:00','15:40:30']}
```

Now for a given parameter say '`identity'=12 ,'date'=10/27/2013 and 'time'=13:20:21` I want to now create a new dataframe which according to the parameters identity ,date selects from the dataframe the row which has the least time difference with the time parameter.

For example for the parameters `'identity'=12 ,'date'=10/27/2013 and 'time'=13:20:21` we have the answer-

```
identity  date        time     difference
12       10/27/2013  13:20:30     9
```

Comment: Can you post your current attempt?

Comment: Please at least cross check and make sure I can paste whatever you post here. I don't want to go adding quotes just so I can paste it.

Comment: Are the given parameters you want to match on in another `DataFrame` somewhere, or a dictionary or a list of tuples or lists?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @coldspeed i added the required quotes

Comment: @ALollz the parameters are given by the user to search in the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

It's not very what your code looks like since you didnt provide us with your attempt. But this should give you clear idea of how to tackle it

```
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

cond = (df['identity'] == 12) 
cond2 = df['date'] == '10/27/2013'

td = datetime.strptime('13:20:21', '%H:%M:%S')

# series of time differnces
min_time_diff = abs(df.loc[cond & cond2]['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S') - td))

# return the row with the minimum time difference
out = df.loc[min_time_diff.idxmin()]

out['differce'] = min_time_diff[min_time_diff.idxmin()].components.seconds
```

OUT:

```
date        10/27/2013
file               342
identity            12
line                 2
time          13:20:30
differce             9
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I am getting empty dataframe as answer on the actual data....my Date is of type <class 'datetime.datetime'> and Time is <class 'datetime.time'>....could that be the case..I removed datatime.striptime as its already in that format